# How to import a .log file(s) with space in the columns and space separating the columns from each other?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple .log files that look similar to the example down below. I can't seem to import them correctly in python. If I use space as delimiter then most of the columns break into multiple ones. The first row shows the names of the columns I want to add. I tried turning the log files into .csv but it did not help.

```
pd.read_csv("A.log",delimiter=r"\s+")
```

```
Date         Time       Employee                                       Floor Department                                           Field            
12/1/2020 08:03:10.429  Engineer(LSA_800 90)                             0   Service                                              Mechanichal engineering, electrical engineering, telecomunication
12/1/2020 08:03:10.642  Engineer(LSA_800 50)                             2   Service                                              Civil engineering
12/1/2020 08:03:10.674  Assistant(Junior Postion)                        0   Administration                                       Administration % 
12/1/2020 08:03:10.856  Assistant(Senior Position)                       2   Administration                                       Administration % 
12/1/2020 08:03:10.901  Project Manager(Senior Position)                 3   Project Management USA                               Project management PR Communication
```

Comment: Looks like maybe it's a tab delimiter, or fixed width, seeing that huge amount of space between employee and floor, for instance

Comment: What happens when you use `delimiter=None`? [Apparently, sniffer should be able to auto-detect the separator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @ALollz, I tried it but it did not work. the file is imported as 1 column.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, When I use "None", the file is imported as a 1 column also.

Comment: It's never going to work like that.  Your fields have embedded spaces -- that's always going to screw up column detection.  You will need to pre-process these using fix column locations to produce a properly quoted CSV file.  That won't be hard.

Comment: @TimRoberts, could you give me please more details on what you mean with "pre-process using fix column locations" ?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have around 10 files and in each file I have around 10000 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will preprocess the file into an acceptable CSV format:

```
columns = [1,11,25,74,78,131]
colpairs = [(a-1,b-1) for a,b in zip(columns,columns[1:]+[999])]

for ln in open('log.txt'):
    parts = [ ln[a:b].rstrip() for a,b in colpairs ]
    print( '"' + '","'.join(parts) + '"' )
```

Comment: Amazing, Thanks a lot, it works perfectly :) @Tim Roberts